# How to get constants value by using Contract name

Tags: contract-development, constant

for example:

```
contract A {
    uint constant public START_TIME = 10;
}
```

---

```
import "./A.sol"

contract B {
    function test() public {
        uint startTime = A.START_TIME;
    }
}
```

---

If I only need the value of constants, I do not need the actual instance, right?

Comment: There's an issue open in solidity's repo https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1290

Answer (score 2):

The constant is defined and stored in the contract. Therefore, you do need the instance of the contract the constant is defined in.

Comment: Solidity should provide this feature, but they didn't.

Comment: I disagree. It's good to define constants in places where they make sense.